# Is there a project to support cross platform builds with javapackager

Tags: javapackager

Javapackager is the 'official' tool to package Java applications as (more or less) native applications (.EXE .app .rpm etc).

It is rather nice but requires building the distributables on every platform you want to support.

This is rather tiresome and actually quite a lot of work and not easily automated and thus beyond a small project's resources.

The reason why it is that way is that it depends heavily on native tools of each platform. For example Inno Setup on Windows.

Rather than reimplementing all that native functionality in Java (this has been done by JWrapper) which while technically clean and attractive solution I'm looking for a way to leverage the existing native tools.

I think the native tools could be utilised by packaging the native executable to such things like WINE Bottles or AppImage or by utilising VirtualBox or some such, though would prefer a solution that would not require installing Windows.

As this is rather a generic problem I would like to join a project that is already heading that way rather than starting from scratch.

But I've not been able to find such a project even though this is not a unique problem.

Hence the question in the title.

Answer (score 1):

You can package a Java application for Linux as an AppImage file which contains both the JRE and the payload application. The result is a single file that can just be executed and will run on almost every Linux distribution.

Comment: Like I wrote I know about AppImage and like it but that was not the question, but thanks for looking into this.